# Image browser using Python

Tags: python, image

I need to browse my gallery using python.
This is my code :

```
import sys
import matplotlib as plt
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename # Open dialog box
from PIL import Image

import cv2, time

def open_File():   

    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("images","*.png")])
    img = filename.read()

    #cv2.imshow("Shapes", filename) # I used cv2 to show image 
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    filename.close()

rw = Tk()                              # Create window
rw.title("Browse image")               #
l1=Label(rw, text="Select image")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
btn1=Button(rw,text="Browse image", width =14)
btn1.grid(row=0, column=3)
btn1.config(command=open_File)

rw.mainloop()
```

**but I get this error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Akhou\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Akhou/Desktop/PFE altran/shape detection/ShapesDetection/PythonApplication2/browse.py", line 31, in open_File
    img = filename.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Can u help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cv2.imread(filename) for reading image e.g

```
def open_File():   

    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("images","*.png")])
    img = cv2.imread(filename)

    cv2.imshow("Shapes", img) # I used cv2 to show image 
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```